# Identityserver4 role-based single sign on

Tags: single-sign-on, identityserver4, roles

Deploy a set of identityserver4 role-based single sign on; Now the student has logged in on the student end, and the administrator has logged in on the management end. The login is indeed the student end account

How to solve it? We still need to deploy two sets of identityserver4